# Are all local variables constructed simultaneously at the beginning of function execution in C?

Tags: c

Say I have a function like this :

```
int myfunc()
{
    int a;
    // do something
    int b;
    // do something
}
```

when I call myfunc() does the memory allocation for b occur right after a ? Or is b created after the first "do something" is done.

Comment: It could be either. There's no observable difference between the two. Since your program can't tell the difference compilers can take either approach.

Comment: The C specification doesn't say, and in fact there may not be any memory allocated for either `a` or `b`. They could both be in registers, or completely optimized out. To see what happens in a particular instance, compile with `-S` and look at the assembly.

Comment: Is there a reason you are asking? If you observe a difference in the behavior when defining here or there, then you are doing something wrong.

Comment: If memory allocation happens it will happen simultaneously for all local variables. The stack pointer is just move sizeof(a)+sizeof(b) further then 'do something' starts to run. There is no such step 'create' a variable, the compiler generates code which leave some room for it.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, the standard does not use the term *constructed*. Variables are *defined* and *initialized* and *assigned to*, but not *constructed*. A definition asks the compiler to *reserve memory* for the variable.

The standard says that the variables with automatic storage duration have a lifetime that extends from *entry* to the *block* until the *execution of the block* ends in any way. They are *initialized* when the corresponding line is *executed*. During its lifetime an object will have memory reserved for it and it will reside at a fixed address.

Given a program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a = 0;

foo:;
    int b = 42;
    print("%d %d\n", a, b);
    a ++;
    b ++;
    goto foo;
}
```

`b` will have a *constant* address for the entire duration of the `main` function, and so does `a`, but `b` is re*initialized* after every `goto`.

---

However the standard also says that an implementation need not produce an executable that does things as set in the standard for as long as the *external behaviour* of the executable is *as if* the program was translated according to the text of standard. This is known as the *as-if rule*. For example if you do not *observe* them having memory reserved for them, or you do not observe their *address*, then compiler need not necessarily reserve memory for them.

For example if you have the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a = 0;
    for ( ; a < 3; a++) {
        printf("*");
    }
}
```

and you ask "when is memory reserved for `a`", then know that both GCC and Clang will, with -O3, compile this to an executable whose machine code is equivalent to that of

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    putchar('*');
    putchar('*');
    putchar('*');
}
```

Now, when did `a` get *"constructed"*?

Answer (score 3):

The C standard doesn't say a thing about this and leaves this to be a system specific implementation detail.

Also, compilers are free to optimize the variables away, place them in registers (rather than memory) or do whatever they want as long as the logic implied by your C program runs as intended (meaning you can't tell the difference).

In practical terms, on most systems (but not all systems), these variable aren't really "allocated" at all - at least not in the normal sense.

These variables live on the "stack", which is often (but not always) a single allocation performed right before execution begins for the thread.

The variables (if not optimized away) represent part of the function's stack "frame", so every time the function is called it will reserve `sizeof(int) * 2` for itself as part of its stack frame.

It's like a stack of dishes in the kitchen. Whenever you call a function, you place it on top of the stack. When a function returns, it (and everything above it) is removed from the stack.

My explanation is so simplified here that it could be considered wrong, but it's close enough to what's happening for you to get the idea (I hope).

You can read more detailed information [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation) or various internet resources such as [this one](https://gribblelab.org/CBootCamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html).